# Why is my SQL so slow?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is reasonably small around 50,000 rows.  My schema is as follows:

### DAILY

- match_id
- user_id
- result
- round
- tournament_id

Query:

```
SELECT user_id 
  FROM `daily` 
 WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id 
                     FROM daily 
                    WHERE round > 25 
                      AND tournament_id = 24 
                      AND (result = 'Won' OR result = 'Lost'))
```

Comment: are all collumns indexed? did you try EXPLAIN SELECT....

Comment: Any particular reason why you need that subquery? Isn't that the same as: `SELECT user_id FROM \`daily\` where round > 25 and tournament_id=24 and (result='Won' or result='Lost')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the in keyword in the fashion you are is a very dangerous [from a performance perspective] thing to do.  It will result in the sub query [(select user_id from daily where round > 25 and tournament_id=24 and (result='Won' or result='Lost'))] being ran 50,000 times in this case.

You'll want to convert this onto a join something to the effect of

```
select user_id from daily a join
       (select user_id from daily where round > 25 and tournament_id=24 and (result='Won' or result='Lost')) b on a.user_id = b.user_id
```

Doing something similar to this will result in only two queries and a join.

As Cybernate pointed out in your specific example you can simply use where clauses, but I went ahead and suggested this in case your query is actually more complex than what you posted.

Comment: -1: The `IN` clause in the example will not result in RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row) execution -- it's scalar.  A **correlated** subquery would be more likely, unless using the `EXISTS` clause.  Fact is, the subquery isn't necessary at all.

Answer (score 2):

First verify and add Indexes as suggested earlier.

Also why are you using an in if you are querying data from same table.
Change your query to:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM   daily 
WHERE  round > 25 
       AND tournament_id = 24 
       AND ( result = 'Won' 
              OR result = 'Lost' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query only needs to be:

```
SELECT d.user_id 
  FROM DAILY d
 WHERE d.round > 25 
   AND d.tournament_id = 24 
   AND d.result IN ('Won', 'Lost')
```

Indexes should be considered on:

- DAILY.round
- DAILY.tournament_id
- DAILY.result

Answer (score 0):

This should return in a millisecond.

```
SELECT user_id FROM daily WITH(NOLOCK) 
where user_id in (select user_id from daily WITH(NOLOCK)  where round > 25 and tournament_id = 24 and (result = 'Won' or result = 'Lost'))
```

Then make sure there is an index on the filter columns.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_1 ON daily (round ASC, tournament_id ASC, result ASC)
```